# Mac OS X virtualization on a PC

Tags: macos, virtualization

Is it possible (and legal, and to be precise: EULA does not necessarily mean law) to buy Mac OS X (without Apple computer) for the purpose of virtualization on a PC?

Comment: No;  Its not possible.  OS X is not sold to anyone that does not have Apple hardware.  The most recent versions are not even sold as they are actually free to existing OS X users.

Comment: @Ramhound What is it, then? http://store.apple.com/pl/product/MC573PL/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard

Comment: First 10.6 isn't a "recent version of OS X.  My comment is very specific for a reason.  Besides you won't be able to purchase it without proving you are already an OS X user.  The duplicate question is out of date, since the accepted solution, isn't even possible anymore.

Comment: We're not lawyers, so asking if it's legal is off-topic. If you have a specific technical question about getting it running, perhaps try posting that (even though it'll still been seen as a [Hackintosh question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed) and probably be closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but with limited success.  It's easiest with older Mac releases where there was still DVD media, but there are instructions out there to show how you can create images from your Mac if running something newer.  You'll need Apple's magic string which is embedded into every Mac is a pseudo encrypted way (again, you can find the magic string by using utilities found on the Internet, shoot, somebody has probably posted it.  btw, the string sort of suggest that what you are likely about to do is illegal).  There are other things you have to do, again, there are many recipes on the Internet, just google.  Maybe that's not a good answer, but the info is out there on many many sites.

So.. you can "do it", but the result is always a violation of Apple's terms (always).  Simply put, Apple does not really "support" the world of virtualization.  At least not yet.

Comment: Why on earth this answer as accepted answer confuses the heck out of me.  This doesn't say if its "possible" to purchase OS X without owning Apple hardware which was what the question was.

Comment: Very true.  It means that you can purchase an Apple product and then there is a "way" to virtualize.  But it's difficult and not permitted (at all) by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

There was a debate on whether this is legal or permitted by the OS X Eula here:

[How should we act upon "Install OS X as virtual machine" questions?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2792/how-should-we-act-upon-install-os-x-as-virtual-machine-questions)